# ifstream EOF executing early

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, ifstream, eof

I'm working with socket programming and am currently attempting to transfer a 1MB file through 16KB at a time. The data does initially transfer 16KB at a time; however, my ifstream reaches EOF prematurely which makes it so the file transfer is incomplete.

```
int main() {

int SIZE = 16000;
char file_buffer[SIZE];
int i = 0;

ifstream my_file("1MB", ios::in | ios::binary);
if (!my_file) {
    cout << "No such file";
} else {
io_service io_service;
// socket creation
ip::tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);

client_socket
    .connect(
        tcp::endpoint(
            address::from_string("127.0.0.1"),
            9999));


while(!my_file.eof()) {
    char ch;

        my_file >> ch;
        if(my_file.eof())
        {
            cout << "File Buffer: " << file_buffer << endl;
            cout << "ERROR: EOF DETECTED" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (i == SIZE)
        {
            sendData(client_socket, file_buffer);
            memset(file_buffer, 0, sizeof file_buffer);
            i = 0;
        } else
        {
            file_buffer[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
    }

}
my_file.close();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: If the file size isn't an exact multiple of `SIZE`, what do you do with what you have in the `file_buffer`? It looks like you just drop that.

Comment: small nitpick: `char` is not `unsigned char`. Since you are dealing with binary data, using `uint8_t` would be better and more explicit.

Comment: Also, `while(!my_file.eof())` is incorrect. Use `unsigned char ch; while(my_file >> ch)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you discard the data at the end of the file if the file size isn't an exact multiple of `SIZE`.

Also, even if the file size is an exact multiple of `SIZE` you'll be reading the last character and then `eof()` will *not* return `true`. Not until you've tried reading the next character will `eof()` return `true`, and that will trigger your error message, `ERROR: EOF DETECTED`.

More on that here:
[Why is `iostream::eof()` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

An alternative approach:

```
unsigned i = 0;

while(my_file >> file_buffer[i]) { // loop for as long as extracting succeeds
    if(++i == SIZE) {
        sendData(client_socket, file_buffer, i);       // add a size parameter
        // memset(file_buffer, 0, sizeof file_buffer); // why waste the time?
        i = 0;
    }
}

if(i) sendData(client_socket, file_buffer, i); // send the last part in the buffer
```